# Access direct URL of image stored in public blob — iOS Content Module

Tags: quickblox

Is there a way to access a direct URL of a public image when I know its blob.ID?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload blob and make it public

```
[QBContent TUploadFile:file fileName:@"Great Image" contentType:@"image/png" isPublic:YES delegate:self];

// QuickBlox queries delegate
- (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{
    // success result
    if(result.success){
        if([result isKindOfClass:QBCFileUploadTaskResult.class]){
            QBCFileUploadTaskResult *res = (QBCFileUploadTaskResult *)result;
            NSString *publicUrl = res.uploadedBlob.publicUrl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is true, but I'm trying to access someone else's public image, so I do not know the publicUrl for it. I guess the only way is the hard way: access user blobId, query for this Blob and get UID and try retrieving this image by UID?

Comment: You can share all your blobs via Custom Objects API - here is my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979930/retrieving-all-blobs-from-opponent-ios-content-chat-modules