# Retrieving all blobs from opponent (iOS Content/Chat Modules)

Tags: quickblox

How can I retrieve all blobs uploaded by 'opponent' (not just opponent.blobId)?
Is there any solution just like PagedRequest for currentUser's blob?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please explain why?

Answer (score 0):

There is no base way to do this, 
because all files can be private or something like this

I propose to do next: use Custom Objects API http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects

Create **UserFiles** or **UserAlbum** table and write all your files (blobx IDs i mean) to it which you want to open to users

Next, other users will be able to retrieve all files - just get all data from this table using filter **user_id=**